# php get the all array values in a single array with key name

Tags: php, mysql

I write these function for fetch records from database in php.But in this array i get all the values in a single array.I want to get 
    this type of result.What to do for get this type of array.

```
Example:    
Array
(
    [city] => Array
        (
            [0] => ABINGTON
            [1] => CHELTENHAM
            [2] => PHILADELPHIA
        )
    [state] => Array
        (
            [0] => Florida
            [1] => Other

        )
```

)

```
public function selectLocations($POST)
    {
        $f1=0;
        $location = array();
        $SELECT_CITY = "SELECT DISTINCT city FROM listings WHERE Matrix_Unique_ID > 0 LIMIT 0,5";
        $cityresult = $this->conn->query($SELECT_CITY);
        while($row = $cityresult->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $location[$f1] = $row['city'];
            $f1++;
        }

        $SELECT_STATE = "SELECT DISTINCT state_or_province FROM listings WHERE Matrix_Unique_ID > 0";
        $stateresult = $this->conn->query($SELECT_STATE);

        while($row1 = $stateresult->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $location[$f1] = $row1['state_or_province'];
            $f1++;
        }

        return $location;
    }
```

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following , it should work for you .

```
public function selectLocations($POST)
    {
        $location = array();
        $SELECT_CITY = "SELECT DISTINCT city FROM listings WHERE Matrix_Unique_ID > 0 LIMIT 0,5";
        $cityresult = $this->conn->query($SELECT_CITY);
        while($row = $cityresult->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $location['city'][] = $row['city'];
        }

        $SELECT_STATE = "SELECT DISTINCT state_or_province FROM listings WHERE Matrix_Unique_ID > 0";
        $stateresult = $this->conn->query($SELECT_STATE);

        while($row1 = $stateresult->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $location['state'][] = $row1['state_or_province'];
        }

        return $location;
    }
```